# Where can one find sneak-peak of features of future releases?

Tags: uds

Is there an source where one can find what features will be available in a particular future-release of ubuntu?

Comment: [UDS](http://uds.ubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Canonical has "Ubuntu Developer Summits" (UDS) sessions. The online version is called Ubuntu Online Summit (UOS). The [Ubuntu Online Summit](http://summit.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/join-a-session/) event is held online and uses a unique mix of live video sessions, integrated chat, and collaborative note-taking and the next one is scheduled for ...

> **UOS November 2015**
>
> Starts: Tue, 03 Nov 2015 14:00:00 UTC
>
> Ends: Thu, 05 Nov 2015 20:00:00 UTC
>
> Ubuntu Online Summit, highlighting work from Ubuntu 15.10 and detailing plans for 16.04

You can find these announcements also on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/sprints/uos-1511).

- The day to day planning for this event:

  - [Tuesday](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uos-1511/2015-11-03/)
  - [Wednesday](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uos-1511/2015-11-04/)
  - [Thursday](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uos-1511/2015-11-05/)
- All of the scheduled events are also [listed](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uos-1511/all/) on 1 page.

(not al lot listed yet but give it a little bit of time).

Reminder: all the URLs point to the 1511 summit. Use the main website ([Summit Ubuntu](http://summit.ubuntu.com/)) to get the latest news.